Reference request: Graph Algorithms
I am looking for a book (or a set of books) on graph algorithms (mainly) that teaches the main techniques used (basic to advanced), as well as explaining how to prove their time complexity and their correctness. I have previously read about many graph algorithms, but I sometimes have trouble proving its correctness even though I intuitively understand the algorithm and its ideas. Hopefully the book is not dry and is relatively easy to read and follow.

There are many algorithms books that cover graphs as a subset, but I don't know of any that focuses solely on graph algorithms. I suggest you consider these:
Intro to Algorithms - CLRS (Ch. 6)
Algorithm Design Manual - Skiena (Ch. 5,6)
Algorithms - Sedgewick (Ch. 4)
For a mathematical treatment, consider:
Graph Theory - West
Graph Theory - Diestel
